# Win10 Cortana failing with "Activation of app [...] CortanaUI failed with error: The remote procedure call failed"

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Last week I upgraded from a clean Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro (64 bit). Immediately after the upgrade I did a Windows Reset to get the clean install feeling. Unfortunately my Start Menu is opening very slow (takes 2 full seconds), and Cortana isn't working. The search bar is in the task bar, but I cannot type in it or anything. I'm currently at build 10240.

After searching on the internet, I did attempt to re-register all packages:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Unfortunately, this did not help.
Every time I open the Start Menu, two errors show up in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: SearchUI.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3d35
Faulting module name: SearchUI.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f3d35
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00000000001423c2
Faulting process id: 0x1468
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0d02f71fa36be
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe
Report Id: 5de0ff92-30e9-4e39-a8b4-3798d067c3df
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.4.8.152_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: CortanaUI
```

and

```
Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: The remote procedure call failed. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.
```

The TWinUI log shows the following:

```
Activation of the app Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The remote procedure call failed..
```

SearchUI.exe in the Cortana folder is V2, datestamp ‎Friday, ‎July ‎10, ‎2015 6:57:17 AM. File version 10.0.10240.16384
KB3081424 fails to install with error code 0x80070bc9.
Any suggestions on where to search next to get Cortana working?

Comment: What do you mean by build 10240? while some people say that was what was releaced, some people said it was terribly buggy.  Did you pick up a nice clean copy of the relaaced one from microsoft?  (or even from any other source, where it was the releaced one, and you know that there is no file corruption?)

Comment: Build 10240 is what I get when I type "ver" on a command line. It's the version that came with the GWX app from Windows Update on Windows 8.1. Installation went without any issues, and the Windows Reset also gave no issues. Just found out that KB3081424 doesnt want to install. (err 0x80070bc9)

Comment: @Psycogeek - What?  The build released to the general public was build 10240 what is confusing about that?

Comment: Because there are different versions of the searchUI. He has some faulting going on with that , and it could be more than a cortana problem , so what version of searchUI.exe do you show in windows 10?   and why is there a  10.0.10240.16401 and a 10.0.10240.16384 , I dont know?

Comment: SearchUI.exe in the Cortana folder is V2, datestamp ‎Friday, ‎July ‎10, ‎2015 6:57:17 AM. File version 10.0.10240.16384

Comment: on aug5th microsoft relaced another cumulative, with a SearchUI created aug2nd with another change a searchUI with version 10.0.10240.16413.

Comment: I have similar symptoms, as do many people, it appears. In my case I upgraded from Windows 7 and my main user account has the problem. A freshly created account does not have the problem, and some people have recommend using a new account and migrating settings from there. I think the fact that it does not happen on all accounts is an interesting clue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried creating a new account, logged in into it, waited for the "setting things up" intro to go away, and it didn't work unfortunately. To be safe I tried it two more times, but with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also. To fix it I had to go to the folder:

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files\

right click, properties, security tab, add the group "all application packages" and give that group full control. once i did that i could get into all of my metro apps again.

Comment: Don't you think that this could be a security concern for the user?

Comment: This did not work for me, but lead me to try applying the change to all of %AppData% for the user which fixed it!